# Django enable logging while run tests

Tags: python, django

how to enable logging when I`m running tests in django? My goal is to save all errors to file.
Here is my config:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'file.log'),
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'apps.hello': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
}
```

This config works good when runserver but when im trying to run tests it save nothing.

Also I tried some hacks before i asked question.
[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255657/how-can-i-disable-logging-while-running-unit-tests-in-python-django)
[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476447/django-logging-when-test-fails)